# pixelsorting self-calling function explanation request

Tags: python, rgb

what does that function do exactly? I understand it sorts pixels by brightness in three diferent lists (lesser, pivot, greater). But i do not quite know how, the self-calling aspect is realy confusing.
I am not very experienced with python and programming in general.

```
def quick_sort(pixels):
#Quicksort function that sorts pixels based on combined RGB values (R + B + G)
if pixels == []:
    return pixels

else:
    pivot = pixels[0]
    lesser = quick_sort([x for x in pixels[1:] if (x[0] + x[1] + x[2]) < (pivot[0] + pivot[1] + pivot[2])])
    greater = quick_sort([x for x in pixels[1:] if (x[0] + x[1] + x[2]) >= (pivot[0] + pivot[1] + pivot[2])])
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

original code:
Copyright (c) 2014 Lycaon (lycaon.me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **just a simple implementation of famous quick-sort** algorithm for array of 3D vectors. The reference algorithm is: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

If you want to sort [5 2 8 4 1 7 9], you pick a "pivot", and sort elements in two groups: smaller and bigger than the pivot. Then, you recursively call the sorting algorithm.

For the previous sample, chosing the first value as the "pivot" (marked with a star) will split the array to:

```
[5* 2 8 4 1 7 9] = [2 4 1] + 5* + [8 7 9].
```

Then, you need apply the algorithm recursively on [2 4 1] and [8 7 9], the resulting array will be sorted. The recursive call will give:

```
[2* 4 1] = [1] + 2* + [4]
[8* 7 9] = [7] + 8* + [9]
```

So:

```
[5 2 8 4 1 7 9] = [1 2 4 5 7 8 9]
```

The pseudocode of the algorithm is:

```
def mergesort(array): 
    pivot = array[0]
    lessThan = [x for x in array[1:] if x < pivot]
    greaterThan = [x for x in array[1:] if x <= pivot]

    return mergesort(lessThan) + [pivot] + mergesort(greaterThan)
```

Here, there's a small change to the reference implementation: we do not compare the elements of the array (it should compare pixels by lexiographic order). It compares the sum of all components of the pixel. It's why the code does:

```
pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2] <= pivot[0] + pivot[1]+pivot[2]
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot for the rapid response and the well written explanation!